# Calculating the mass of a surface?

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals

I have equation for a surface, $ z = 2/3(x^{3/2} + y^{3/2}) $ with $0 \leq x \leq 1$, $0 \leq y \leq 1$ which has the density of $g(x,y,z) = 120$.

I need to set up a double integral for the mass of this surface. Basically I'm not sure where the $120$ comes into play and what to do with it, or even how to begin the problem.

Comment: there seems to be some information missing... A surface doesn't have mass, so are you looking for the mass of the space between this surface and the xy-plane?

If that is the case, you want to calculate the volume of that space, then multiply by the density to get the mass.

Comment: Given a density in 3 dimensions, the integral over a 2 dimensional surface gives mass per unit length.

Comment: For some applications it makes sense to consider a thin shell of positive mass.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a small section of your surface of area $\Delta S$ where the density doesn't change much, then its mass is going to be roughly the density times the area, i.e. $g \Delta S$. Summing over all such small pieces gives us an approximate total mass of $\sum g\Delta S$, and taking the limit as $\Delta S \rightarrow 0$ leaves us with:

Mass = $\displaystyle \int_S g \, dS$

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that $g(x,y,z)$ represents the *mass per unit area* of the surface.  In that case, to find the total mass of the surface, you need to integrate
$$
\int_{x=0}^{1}\int_{y=0}^{1}g(x,y,z(x,y))dS,
$$
where $z(x,y)=\frac{2}{3}\left(x^{3/2}+y^{3/2}\right)$, and the area element $dS$ is
$$
dS=dx\;dy\;\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^2}.
$$
In your case
$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\sqrt{x}, \qquad \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\sqrt{y},
$$
so
$$
dS=dx \;dy\;\sqrt{1+x+y}.
$$
The total mass is therefore
$$
m=120\int_{0}^{1}dx\int_{0}^{1}dy\sqrt{1+x+y}.
$$
You should be able to take it from here.